# What is the difference between . and the current directory?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to copy the current directory as a source. Using full paths gives me the expected behaviour, copying the entire directory into the destination.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir a b
$ cd a
$ touch 1 2 3
$ cp -r /tmp/a /tmp/b # use /tmp/a as source
$ ls /tmp/b
a
```

However, using `.` to refer to the source copies the *contents* of the source instead of the directory itself.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir c
$ cd a
$ cp -r . /tmp/c # use . as source
$ ls /tmp/c
1 2 3
```

What is the difference between `.` and the absolute path of the current directory? If I want to copy the current directory itself, is there a short reference? (The only way I could see was to use `../a`, which seems slightly redundant.)

Comment: . is also used to execute a script.  It will also specify the current directory for citing a command or script to run from the current directory vs. the $PATH.  e.g. ".  ./ping" to run your own custom ping script.

Comment: @MikeP Right, but in this case specifying the full path or `.` would still have the same result. e.g. `/path/to/custom/ping` vs. `./ping`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case you're asking `cp` to copy `/tmp/a` and its contents to `/tmp/b`; so first `a` is copied, to `/tmp/b/a`, then `a`'s contents are copied into `/tmp/b/a`.

In the second case you're asking `cp` to copy `.` and its contents to `/tmp/b`; using the same thought process as above, we can think of this as copying `.` first, to `/tmp/b/.` (*i.e.* `/tmp/b`), then copying `.`'s contents into `/tmp/b/.`.

There is no short reference for the current directory which can work in all cases, since the current directory may have different names (using symlinks). I think the closest you can get is `$PWD`.

Comment: Ahhh… so if I understand correctly, it's not like there is variable expansion of `.` in the first place (as would occur if I used `$PWD`)? The shell copies a pseudo-filename `.`, which has a different meaning depending on its parent directory.

Comment: Yes, the shell doesn't process `.` at all; that's just passed to `cp`. The shell itself isn't involved in copying. `.` is just a special directory which exists everywhere and points to itself (look at the inode numbers you get when you run `cd /tmp/a; ls -ail; ls -aild ../a`, you'll see the inode for `.` when you're in `/tmp/a` is the same as `/tmp/a`'s).

Comment: `.` and `..` are aliases added on filesystem interpretation level in OS. `.` is always pointing to the current directory. `..` is always pointing to it's parent, or in case of `/`, to itself. These are shell independent. So why have `$PWD`? Because it returns the whole path as text. `.` is always relative.

Answer (score 3):

Using `.` has certain advantages. E.g. you can copy a directory without having to care whether it already exists as target (the parent directory does have to exist, though):

Depending on whether `/tmp/target` is an existing directory the command

```
cp -a /path/to/source/dir /tmp/target
```

leads to different results. But

```
cp -a /path/to/source/dir/. /tmp/target
```

has the same result in both cases.